# Can't get polymer databinding to custom html tag to work while it works on standard tags

Tags: html, css, data-binding, polymer

I'm using polymer 1.3.1 but can't get the following to work inside a polymer-element named: `poly-main`. The text of the `<div>` should be in red but isn't.

```
<div  testcolor="[[colorLocalRed]]">
-->ERROR This must be RED because testcolor="[[colorLocalRed]]"
(expected "myred" and styles.css translates this to color="red")
</div>
```

with the following at the start of the script tag:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'poly-main',
  properties: {
    colorLocalRed: {
      type: String,
      value: "myred",
      notify: true
    },
```

And the following inside styles.css:'

```
[testcolor="myred"] {
  color: red;
}
```

Note: the following works as it should:
    `<div  testcolor="myred"> some red text </div>`

Not using the custom tag `testcolor` but using directly style or color is not an option because this example is only to show the problem of databinding to a non-standard html-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
<div  testcolor$="[[colorLocalRed]]">
```

Adding `$` to the attribute name binds to the attribute instead of the property which can't be addressed in CSS.

For more details see https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#native-binding

Comment: thanks, it works and that after 35 seconds.Can you point me to more on the topic of using the $. (`testcolor$="myred"` does not work but still must be expressed as `testcolor="myred"`

Comment: I added the link to my answer.